# how to get value of dropdown in PHP_SELF post method

Tags: php, forms, post

I am using the following code to get value of input text box and it is working perfect but what should be my code if i want to get value of a select box. (i.e) dropdown box.

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER[’PHP_SELF’];?>" id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8">
    <tr>
      <td><span class="enquiry_text">Name*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php $_SESSION['myForm']['fname']; ?>" class="enquiry_width_1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="enquiry_text">Post Applied For*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><select name="jobopening" class="enquiry_width_1" id="jobopening"  value="<?= $_SESSION['myForm']['jobopening']; ?>" >
          <option value="">Select </option>
          <option value="Site Engineer">Site Engineer</option>
          <option value="Project Engineer">Project Engineer</option>
          <option value="Project Manager">Project Manager</option>
          <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
          <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
          <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
          <option value="Store Keeper">Store Keeper</option>
          <option value="Other Position">Other Position</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="enquiry_text">Qualification*</span></td>
    </tr>
```

please tell me how can i get values of drop down.  what should be my code if i want to get value of a select box. (i.e) dropdown box.

Comment: You have the wrong types of quotes around `PHP_SELF`. Don't use "smart quotes" when writing code.

Comment: Why do you think it makes a difference that you're using `PHP_SELF`? Reading form values is the same no matter how you name the script.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to use `PHP_SELF` in the first place. If you use `action=""`, that means to submit to the current URL.

Comment: @Barmar i am new to PHP sir, the values typed in the input text boxes are passed when the form is submitted. but the value we select in dropdown is not passed. can you tell me how can i get it?

Comment: The value from select will be in `$_POST['jobopening']`

Comment: Also in `select` tag you shouldn't put `value` attribute, only `option` tag should have this attribute

Comment: `code` function process_form() {
 // Read POST request params into global vars
 
 $namefrom = trim($_POST['fname']); //Required
 $jobopening = $_POST['jobopening']; //Required 
 echo "<script> alert('$jobopening');</script>";
 $qualification = $_post['qualification']; //Required

Comment: @divaka yes i am getting the values from text box even though i use $_POST['jobopening']; i dont get the value

Comment: I see 2 things that's bothering me: 1. `value` attribute inside the `select` tag, remove `value=` from the `select` tag. 2. Did not see closing tag `</form>` for your form. Check for these, too and add `var_dump($_POST)` in your question, please.

Comment: @Barmar It works fine when i removed the PHP_SELF and used action="" thank you so much

Comment: @divaka as your suggestion i removed the value= from the select tag. and now it is working fine. thanks for the response. Between i did not  understand this "add var_dump($_POST) in your question".

Comment: As far as it's working don't worry about it :) Glad I've helped!

Comment: @divaka Happy to get help from you too

Answer (score 0):

It will be in the $_POST variable

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Use print_r to view it

https://www.php.net/print_r